# C++ Friend method cannot access private data from class

Tags: c++, class, friend

I am doing my project which is simulation of school system.
I have problem with the fact that a method from class Klasa (Polish for class) cannot access private data from class Student, even though I declared this method as a friend in Student.

Here is the code:

First Student.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Klasa.h"
#include "SubjectType.h"
#include "SubjectGrades.h"
using namespace std;
    class Klasa;
    class SubjectGrades;

    class Student
    {
    private:
        char* name;
        int id;


        Klasa* myClass;
        //School* mySchool;
        int classIndex; //numer w dzienniku - zrobić prywatne z akcesorami
        static int counter;
    public:



        Student();
        Student(char*);
        Student(const Student&);
        Student& operator= (const Student&);
        ~Student();

        //bool assignToSchool(School*)
        //bool resignFromSchool();
        void assignToClass(Klasa*);
        void resignFromClass();
        double getMyAverageGrade(SubjectType type) const ;      //srednia ocen z danego przedmiotu dla danego ucznia
        double getMyAverageGrade() const;       //średnia ocen dla danego ucznia

        bool operator== (const Student&);
        bool operator!= (const Student&);
        friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, const Student&);
        // akcesory
        int GetclassIndex() const;
        int SetclassIndex(int i);
        friend bool Klasa::assignToKlasa(Student* s);
        char* GetName() const { return name; }
    };
```

Now method from class Klasa:

```
    bool Klasa::assignToKlasa(Student* s)
    {
        if(studentCount < maxStudentCount)
        {
            if(containsStudent(s))
                return false;

            if(studentCount < klasaSize) //jest miejsce dla studenta
            {
                int i = 0;
                while(studentList[i] != NULL)
                    i++;
                studentList[i] = s;

                s->classIndex=i;// = i; //tu musi byc setter
            }
            //WHATS BELOW DOESN'T MATTER FOR THIS PROBLEM, SO U DON;T NEED TO READ.


            else
            {
                cout << "Zwiekszamy rozmiar!\n";
                //musimy zwiększyć rozmiar tablicy studentList
                Student** newStudentList = new Student*[klasaSize + sizeStep];
                for(int i = 0; i < klasaSize; ++i)
                    newStudentList[i] = studentList[i];

                for(int i = klasaSize; i < klasaSize + sizeStep; ++i)
                    newStudentList[i] = NULL;

                klasaSize += sizeStep;

                delete[] studentList;
                studentList = newStudentList;

                studentList[studentCount] = s;

                s->SetclassIndex(studentCount); //tu ma byc setter

            }

            s->assignToClass(this); //mówimy studentowi - "jestem twoją klasą"
            studentCount++;
            cout << "Dodano studenta!\n";

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

It underlines `s->classIndex=i` that classIndex cannot be accessed.

Also in Klasa.h I declared this method like: `bool assignToKlasa(Student* s);`

So I have no idea why it doesn't let me access private data from student after I declared it in student as a friend? Could you please help me?

Comment: Where exactly did you define that Klasa is a friend class for Student?

Comment: Klasa isn't friend class for student. Method from class Klasa is a friend method for class Student and its declared in Student.h .

Comment: @ViteFalcon - He didn't. He declared that a *member* of Klasa is a friend: `friend bool Klasa::assignToKlasa(Student* s);`

Comment: He didnt say he declared the entire class as friend, just a method of that class

Comment: @SteveJessop i think that is the problem as well, you should write is an answer.

Comment: OK, well if two people think it's right then I'll go for it! I'm just a bit puzzled why there's no error reported at the line with the `friend` declaration.

Comment: What is the error message that you are getting?

Answer (score 4):

Your definition of `class Student { ... }` shouldn't compile either. The `friend` declaration is an error, so I'm surprised that isn't highlighted too. What your IDE has figured out is that the access to a private member isn't allowed without a working `friend` declaration.

The error is that a forward declaration of `Klasa` is not enough to declare a member function of `Klasa` to be a friend of `Student`. You need the class definition of `Klasa` first.

So, it should be:

```
class Student; // forward declaration, because members of Klasa take Student*

class Klasa { 
    ... 
};

class Student { 
    ... 
};
```

then you can define `Klasa::assignToKlasa`.

Comment: Sorry I didn;t paste whole student.h , of course in Student.h there is also                                                     #include <iostream>
#include "Klasa.h"
#include "SubjectType.h"
#include "SubjectGrades.h"
using namespace std;

Comment: @MelsNoob: in that case I'm not sure, you may need to to produce a self-contained example of the problem. My best guess is that maybe you've got some circular includes, so that in fact the definition of class `Student` does occur before the definition of class `Klasa`. To be sure, preprocess the source file that causes the problem (`Klasa.cpp`, I suppose) and you'll see exactly what the compiler sees.

Answer (score 1):

For this equivalent code

```
class A;
class B {
  int x;
public:
  B(int __x) : x(__x) {}
  friend bool A::method(B*) const;   // error: undefined member cannot be friend
//friend class A;                    // fine:  class A is declared and can be used
};

class A {
  int y;
pu8blic:
  A(int __y) : y(__y) {}
  bool method(B*b) const
  { return y == b->x; }
};
```

I get the error messages (with gcc 4.3.2):

test3.cc:7: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct A’

test3.cc:1: error: forward declaration of ‘struct A’

test3.cc: In member function ‘bool A::method(B*) const’:

test3.cc:3: error: ‘int B::x’ is private

test3.cc:15: error: within this context

The first error is the *only* one you have to worry about (the others are either explanations or consequences of the first). So how can one sort this out? One simple way to fix the problem is to declare the whole `class A` to be friend of `B` by replacing

```
  friend bool A::method(B*) const;
```

with

```
  friend class A;
```

which is defined.

Comment: i don;t understand as I am new to this stuff, could you explain profusely?

Comment: @MelsNoob Well, you cannot declare a the member functions of a class `A` to be friend of `B` before you have declared `A` to have such a member function, i.e. before the declaration of class `A`. The failing access is just a follow-up error. Always start sorting out the first error, before worrying about later ones, as many will just be consequences of the first one and disappear once you sorted out the first.

Comment: @Mels: this answer is basically the same as mine, but it has a code example and mine doesn't. "invalid use of incomplete type" means the same as "a forward declaration is not enough ... you need the class definition". A forward declaration of a class creates an incomplete type, the class definition creates a complete type.

Comment: Thank you guys Walter as well as @Steve Jessop , so basically to use friend method from another class i need to have those 2 classes' definitions in 1 header yes?

Comment: @MelsNoob **NO**. 1) To declare a member function of another class to be friend, the full definition of the other class must have been seen by the compiler (can be in another header which is #included). 2) To declare a whole class (and hence all its members) to be friend, the class only needs to have been declared, which can be a forward declaration.